# Dependency Property in ContentDialog works only in one direction

Tags: c#, xaml, dependency-properties, winui-3

I got a problem concerning `ContentDialogs` in WinUI 3.
I have a Panel opening a `ContentDialog`.
The `ContentDialog` contains a `TextBox`.

The Panel has a property that should store the Text that has been typed into the `TextBox` of the `ContentDialog`. Also the `TextBox` should initially be filled with the original value of the property from the Panel

To achieve that I tried to inject a dependency property into the Dialog, which is TwoWay binded to the `TextBox` in the UI.

### Expected behavior

I assumed that the Text written into the `TextBox` should be transferred to the Property of the Panel.
However this is not the case.

### Current behavior

The `TextBox` gets its initial value from the property but the property is not updated, if I change the Text in the `TextBox`.

Why is that?

### Here is a small sketch

[Sketch of the setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSyn2.png)

### Code example

#### Dependency property in panel (the panel gets this property injected as well)

```cs
public string? PanelTextBoxValue
{
    get => (string?)GetValue(PanelTextBoxValueProperty);
    set => SetValue(PanelTextBoxValueProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty PanelTextBoxValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(PanelTextBoxValue),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(Panel),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

#### Method to open the dialog

```cs
private async void ShowTextBoxDialog()
{
    var dialog = new TextBoxDialog()
    {
        TextBoxValue = PanelTextBoxValue,
    };
    dialog.XamlRoot = XamlRoot;
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

#### Dependency property in Dialog

```cs
public string? TextBoxValue
{
    get => (string?)GetValue(TextBoxValueProperty);
    set => SetValue(TextBoxValueProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(TextBoxValue),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(TextBoxDialog),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

#### Corresponding part of the Dialog.xaml

```xml
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Line 1:" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBox Name="Line1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{x:Bind TextBoxValue, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

### What I've seen

If I change the value of the TextBox in the Dialog the `TextBoxValue` property is updated as it should (set a breakpoint in the set method).
However the `PanelTextBoxValue` is not updated.

let me know if you need anything else!
I am a bit clueless because it works in one direction but not in the other.

Comment: the only code shown which transfers the value is `TextBoxValue = PanelTextBoxValue` which copies the value once from Panel to Dialog. There is no Binding between TextBoxValue dependencyProperty and PanelTextBoxValue dependencyProperty. are you missing a `PanelTextBoxValue = dialog.TextBoxValue` after `await dialog.ShowAsync();`?

Comment: @Firo all in all there are ten textboxes in the final dialog so simply saying ```PanelTextBoxValue = dialog.textBoxValue``` would not work. I thought by saying ```TextBoxValue = PanelTextBoxValue``` I would pass a reference and not a value as I was used to with other dependency properties in different parts of my application (for example with the dependency property injected into my Panel) isn't that the case here?

Comment: @Firo My bad, misunderstood your comment. Yes this seems to work but somehow looks not really clean but hacky. Thanks for the work around regardless. Would you mind doing this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Firo If I do it that way do I even need to have Dependency Properties in the Dialog xaml.cs?

Comment: No. My adivce would be to use an object as source for the value (a model or a viewmodel) and then bind PanelTextBoxValue and TextBoxValue to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only code shown which transfers the value is `TextBoxValue = PanelTextBoxValue` which copies the value once from Panel to Dialog.
There is no Binding between TextBoxValue dependencyProperty and PanelTextBoxValue dependencyProperty.

Option 1: Simple

```
...
await dialog.ShowAsync();
PanelTextBoxValue = dialog.TextBoxValue;
```

Option 2: For real time syncing

```
SetBinding(PanelTextBoxValueProperty, new System.Windows.Data.Binding
{
    Path = new PropertyPath(TextBoxDialog.TextBoxValueProperty),
    Source = dialog
});
await dialog.ShowAsync();
BindingOperations.ClearBinding(this, PanelTextBoxValueProperty);
```